# Вывод кириллицы в xlwt Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, excel, unicode

Я просто хотел подсветить колонки с id... простите за качество кода

```
st = xlwt.easyxf('pattern: pattern solid;')
st.pattern.pattern_fore_colour = 3

with xlrd.open_workbook(filename) as book:

    wBook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding="utf-8") # главное не ascii который default

    for sheetIndex in range(book.nsheets):
        sheet = book.sheet_by_index(sheetIndex)
        wSheet = wBook.add_sheet(sheet.name)
        header = findHeader(sheet, True)
        header.checkSelf()

        for rowIndex in range(sheet.nrows):
            row = sheet.row(rowIndex)

            for columnIndex in range(len(row)):
                cell = row[columnIndex]

                if(int(cell.ctype) in (1, 2)):
                    if(columnIndex == header.indexOfId and cell.value in idList):
                        wSheet.write(rowIndex, columnIndex, str(cell.value), st)
                        cell.ctype = 2
                    else:
                        wSheet.write(rowIndex, columnIndex, str(cell.value))
```

если попадается ячейка с кириллицей он будет просто молча записывать. конечно же файл потом ругаться на повреждение

если начать шаманить с `str().encode('whatever') str.decode('whatever')` то рано или поздно он обмолвится на `UnicodeEncodeError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поиск решения привел меня к [коммиту](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/commit/457bb3587ab8eb5f9cd6e6e2639d682512911708) на github который полностью решил проблему без дополнительных костылей.

в файле xlwt/BIFFRecords.py всего лишь надо поменять две строчки

```
@@ -91,7 +91,7 @@ def get_biff_record(self):
    def _add_to_sst(self, s):
          u_str = upack2(s, self.encoding)

 -        is_unicode_str = u_str[2] == b'\x01'
 +        is_unicode_str = u_str[2] == b'\x01'[0]
          if is_unicode_str:
              atom_len = 5 # 2 byte -- len,
                           # 1 byte -- options,
 @@ -106,7 +106,7 @@ def _add_to_sst(self, s):

      def _add_rt_to_sst(self, rt):
          rt_str, rt_fr = upack2rt(rt, self.encoding)
 -        is_unicode_str = rt_str[2] == b'\x09'
 +        is_unicode_str = rt_str[2] == b'\x09'[0]
          if is_unicode_str:
              atom_len = 7 # 2 byte -- len,
                           # 1 byte -- options,
```

xlwt, xlrd и xlutils были написаны для Python 2.x и имеют довольно плохую совместимость с Python 3.х, кроме xlutils, он вообще отказывается устанавливаться и работать